# Answer to a question about a compiler bug saying "report the bug" was deleted

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, moderation

A guy has some code and two compile-time-errors inside, which he found by himself! He's already found the errors, understands the problem, and knows the solution.

When he tries to compile that code, he is wondering why the compiler only reports one error even when there are two. He understands what he must change to solve the two errors, so concerning the errors he has no questions.

> Shouldn't I get a compile error both times?

Now the guy opens [a question about why the compiler reports only the first error and not both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41673016). **He is absolutely not asking about the error; he is asking about the report-strategy of the compiler**.

Now his question about the compiler is good and it turns out to be a bug inside the compiler. The answer is to report this bug inside the compiler to the compiler-company. I posted this as an answer. That answer is down-voted 4 times and deleted by a moderator because it is supposedly "not useful". There are also 2 answers explaining what to do to solve the errors.

This question will never be solved because those answers do not answer the question. In addition, the question is marked as a duplicate of a question concerning the errors inside the code, and not the report-strategy of the compiler.

What shall I do?

### Edit: I was wrong

@Holger turnes out that there are no two errors and I was wrong. Shame on me! There never was two bugs that should be reported.

Comment: Your answer is nothing more than a 'post a bug report' link. That should have been posted as a comment, or given a proper explanation as to why it is a bug.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Who, besides perhaps the compiler authors, is going to be particularly interested in an explanation of why it's a bug?  Even if he could dig up some specs on the compiler to explain why it ought to show both errors, would that be useful for the reader?  And even so, that's only an argument for it being a low quality answer due to it being poorly explained, that doesn't make it "not an answer".  It's an answer to the question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It is not a comment, it is a solution. I dare you he will report it to the bug-database of the compiler and answer his own question by "Was a bug, had reported on xxx" and accept his own answer as correct.

Comment: @Servy: it sounded very much like a 'see here' issue. Perhaps it was the wording, but I saw it as NAA, which is how it was flagged.

Comment: @PeterRader: at which point someone will once again flag it as Not an Answer, and the circle will be closed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The user asked why the compiler did X.  There was an answer given that, "it's a bug in the compiler".  That's an answer to the question of why the compiler did X.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If someone incorrectly flags an answer as NAA you're not obligated to delete it just because it's flagged.  Decline the incorrect flag, because the flag is incorrect, rather than accepting it when it's wrong because...what, that's easier?

Comment: He didn't just delete it because it was flagged as NAA. He did so because he "saw it as NAA, which it how it was flagged".

Comment: @Servy: of course I'm not going to delete a post when a NAA flag is incorrect. I didn't think the flag was incorrect.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's answering the question.  How is "that's a compiler bug" *not* an answer to the question of, "why is the compiler not showing this error?"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the poster now admits that they were incorrect and that the problem as reported by the question does not exist.

Comment: @BobJarvis I accept and tried to delete but i cant because of valid answers.

Comment: @PeterRader although you were wrong about the compiler bug, this meta question is still useful as a reference for similar problems.

Answer (score 27):

Your answer should never have been deleted.

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224449/sanity-check-on-naa-flag/224452#224452) are examples of NAA.

Here they are transcribed:

1. I have a question...
2. @someUser: I think that...
3. I like turtles.
4. aj098243u5in (cat on keyboard)

[Here is the epic apple analogy that explains what "not an answer" is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).  This is not an orange, it is an apple.  It may not be a great apple, but it is an apple.

Your answer was an answer.  It may or may not have been a good one or a correct one, but a bad answer (barring an extreme case) does not justify deletion by a moderator.  My opinion is your answer was good and correct, but that is subjective.

The fact that your answer was short and had a link does not make it not an answer.  Removing your link, your answer reads "This is a bug in the compiler", which is both formatted like an answer (and hence, ignoring technical issues, **is an answer**, and is not **not an answer**), and is even an answer to the question asked (why is the compiler only giving one error message instead of two).

Your downvoting is to be expected, because your answer looked brief and didn't elaborate.  People who skim over questions and answers and quickly downvote short, mostly link answers exist, and are more common than people who read over questions well and determine if the answer is good or not.

Without supporting evidence in your answer, unless they personally confirm the bug they may be reluctant to upvote a possibly incorrect answer.

So you only collect downvotes.  And people see a short, mostly link, downvoted answer, and they click on flag.

The moderator sees a short, downvoted, mostly link answer, and does the wrong thing.  Also to be expected, lots of flags to process.

To defend against this, you have to provide supporting evidence for your assertion.  This both makes the drive-by casual downvoters less likely to downvote, the considered upvoters more likely to upvote, and makes moderator error less likely.

Comment: "Your downvoting is to be expected, because your answer looked brief and didn't elaborate." -- that, and the fact that as shown by the other answers it is in fact wrong.

Comment: The fact that compiler authors (and seemingly, most users) of one particular compiler do not consider this a bug does not make the answer wrong. There are other languages for which both errors are reported in OP's code (when it's adjusted to conform to other language syntax and semantics, of course).

Comment: Even with the apple/orange analogy, both users and mods are still confused in certain situations. I also thought this was an answer, though probably a VLQ one.

Answer (score 10):

It was flagged as *Not an Answer*. When I processed the flag, I read it as *see here* link-only post, so I deleted it.

You have edited the post into a slightly better shape since, I've undeleted the post again.

Comment: The original revision was not at all a "see here" with only a link.  The text of the answer, ignoring the link entirely, was unequivocally an answer to the question.  You could argue it wasn't a *good* answer, but there's no doubt at all that it was *an answer*.

Comment: The edit only contains the real question. This makes the answer better in quality. To not have this higher quality (to copy the question) must cause a deletion instead of down-vote of an moderator?

Comment: @PeterRader: I probably was misreading the answer at the time; the 4 downvotes, the link, the grammar mistake and the brevity all contributed, I'd say. I probably read it as 'You found a bug, reported here' more than anything.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That would *also* be an answer to the question, even if that's what it said.

Comment: In short, "You found a bug" is an answer to a question.  It is short, and doesn't elaborate.  It may not be an answer to the OP's question in all situations; in this case, it *is* an answer to "why do I only get one error".  It may not be a high quality one, but it is *an answer*.  It isn't random jibberish; it is coherant, and possibly correct, so it isn't a "low quality answer".  Deleting an answer is not the correct operation.  Deleting using moderator level delete doubly so.  Peter editing it "into shape" is irrelevant.